# Understanding ssh X11 forwarding

Tags: ssh, x11, virtual-machine, xforwarding, container

I have a rather odd setup I'm trying to get working.

I have an Ubuntu install running in a container (through Proxmox). The host computer is CentOS. Neither server is running an X instance.

My host machine is physically plugged into a monitor. My end goal is to be able to `ssh -X` from the host to the container and run `xbmc` so that it displays on my monitor.

Some questions about this setup:

- I need `X` installed on the host too right?
- What exactly are "displays" (like `:0` and `:1`) and do I need to set them?
- Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - I need X installed on the host too, right?

**You need an X server installed on the host *only***, and it will need to be running. You will need some X client libraries in the container (installing `xbmc` will presumably pull these in as dependencies), but not an X server.

> - What exactly are "displays" (like :0 and :1) and do I need to set them?

Displays are distinct (hypothetical) screens managed by a particular server, and the `DISPLAY` environment variable tells X clients how to connect. **`ssh -X` sets that up automatically; you don't need to do anything**.

It is possible to do this without involving `ssh` at all, using X natively. In that case you will need to set up `DISPLAY` appropriately. There's no particular advantage in that for you in these circumstances, other than lowering the resource cost from encrypting the connection.

If you are not running the `ssh` command from inside the host's X server environment you will need to set `DISPLAY=:0` (or similar) explicitly on that end so that `ssh` can see it.

> - Is what I'm trying to do possible?

**Yes**, it is almost the purpose of the X protocol.

---

You should check [`man ssh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) for details of the `-X` and `-Y` options, and [`man ssh_config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) for details of the `ForwardX11Trusted` option. In your case it's likely that the security concerns don't really apply, but do check and make sure.

In particular, `ssh -Y` has a higher success rate in some configurations, but gives the remote end unrestricted access to your X server, while `ssh -X` prevents many such accesses and forces the authentication to expire after a short time. The X protocol is not terribly secure and a client with unrestricted access can, for example, log every keypress made in every other client.

Comment: Is there a way of running `X` on the host without having a desktop environment? I'd rather keep it as lightweight as possible.

Comment: Yes, just don't install one. I suggest you will probably want a window manager of some sort (maybe Fluxbox), but you could strictly get away with the `ssh` command in `.xinitrc` or as your session command.